# Light fitting won't work with more than one bulb in place

Tags: dimmer-switch, light, fitting

I have a light fitting very similar to [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ROMKE-Ceiling-Spotlight-Adjustable-Hallways/dp/B07LF4H4BS).

i have purchased the correct bulbs but when more than one is fitted none work. i have tested each individual fitting and each works. i have purchased a different make of bulb and tried again with the same result.

the switch is a dimmable switch and the [bulbs](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSDUE-Spotlights-220-240V-Halogen-Lamp-Reflector/dp/B07PYZWYGT) say suitable for dimmer use. any ideas wht's wrong? thanks, Joe

Comment: Can you give us a link or photo of the exact the bulbs you've tried?

Comment: many thanks, here you go, OSDUE GU10 Halogen Spotlights, GU10 Halogen Bulb 6PCS 50W 220-240V Halogen-Lamp, 2700K Warm White, Dimmable Halogen Reflector

Comment: I hope you're only using these Amazon items as *exemplars of the type of item*, and not actually buying any of this Marketplace garbage.  (Note where it says, right under the Buy Now button, "**Sold by random_jackass** and Fulfilled by Amazon" - that is Amazon Marketplace and it is all cheap Cheese junk, regardless of the prices they dare to charge).  Those items don't meet EU safety standards, despite the faked CE mark, and liability for that rests on the importer, who is the end-user purchaser!

Answer (score 4):

Your fixture is made to use a set of 4 x 4W LED bulbs (for a total of 16W), but you're trying to use 50W halogen bulbs instead.
This is extremely unsafe, because the halogens give out orders of magnitude more heat than the LEDs do, and your fixture is not made to survive all that heat.
It's a good thing that it's "smart" enough to "see" that you're overloading it and shut down instead of just work for a while before catching fire.
You need to get some GU10 **LED** bulbs to use in that fixture.

Comment: wow, that would explain why I don't do DIY! Many thanks, i shall source the correct bulbs and replace immediately. Joe